# PyScripter Python 2.7 - summarize lines of code into one line (visually)

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyscripter

I was previously working on C++ on VisualStudio and when I was creating a Class, a Function or some lines of code, I remember I could "summarize" all the lines relative to one function for example into only one line that had the name of the function and a little "+" on the side and when you clicked on it, it showed you the entire function code associated with. It was really usefull in order to see clearly through a script not by showing the entire (non necessary) code.

I was wondering if it's possible with Python on PyScripter and how to do this? I have a lot of functions or lines that I would like to "hide" and just summarize as one (describing the name of the function, or just a comment) to see more clearly through my code.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is called code folding. Recent versions of PyScripter provide code folding.  Download PyScripter from https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyscripter/files.